# Regex start with a word till specific word/char/space

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The string could be as following line by line every time.

```
code=876 and town=87 and geocode in(1,2,3)
code=876 and town=878 and geocode in(1,2,3)
code=876 and town="878" and geocode in(1,2,3)
code=876 and town=8,43 and geocode in(1,2,3)
code=876 and town='8,43' and geocode in(1,2,3)
code=876 and town=-1 and geocode in(1,2,3)
code=876 and town=N/A and geocode in(1,2,3)
```

The result should be with preg_match

```
town=87
town=878
town="878"
town=8,43
town='8,43'
town=-1
town=N/A
```

*Note: I know there are various ways to achieve this task but I want to regex only. Thanks*

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? strpos and substr is pretty sufficient for this task.

Comment: Yes, I know. But want to achieve this with regex, please answer the best solution.

Comment: I won't argue with you which method is the best one - but if you're having trouble writing a regex, you may consider using a method you fully understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `preg_match_all`, with the following regex pattern:

```
town=\S+
```

This says to match `town=` followed by any number of *non* whitespace characters.  The matches are then made available in an output array.

```
$input = "code=876 and town=87 and geocode in(1,2,3)";
$input .= "code=876 and town=878 and geocode in(1,2,3)";
$input .= "code=876 and town=\"878\" and geocode in(1,2,3)";
$input .= "code=876 and town=8,43 and geocode in(1,2,3)";
$input .= "code=876 and town='8,43' and geocode in(1,2,3)";
$input .= "code=876 and town=-1 and geocode in(1,2,3)";
$input .= "code=876 and town=N/A and geocode in(1,2,3)";
preg_match_all("/town=\S+/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

Array
(
    [0] => town=87
    [1] => town=878
    [2] => town="878"
    [3] => town=8,43
    [4] => town='8,43'
    [5] => town=-1
    [6] => town=N/A
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use explode and explode on space.

```
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $str) as $line){
    echo explode(" ", $line)[2];
}
```

Outputs:

```
town=87
town=878
town="878"
town=8,43
town='8,43'
town=-1
town=N/A
```

https://3v4l.org/MOUhm

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$str = "code=876 and town=87 and geocode in(1,2,3)";
echo explode(" and ",$str)[1];
```